# Null Pointer exception on a Map get()

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, aggregate

I'm getting the following error because of this line of code (line 235) in my Before Update Trigger on Site Survey (when I hardcode the sum here, the test passes):

Integer sum = Integer.valueOf(aggSum.get('riskScoreTotal'));

```
System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0o1k000001u0J2AAI; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, SiteSurvey_Trigger: execution of BeforeUpdate

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Class.SiteSurvey_TriggerHandler.updateRiskScoreTotalOnSiteSurvey: line 235, column 1
Class.SiteSurvey_TriggerHandler.beforeUpdate: line 33, column 1
Class.TriggerHandler.handleTrigger: line 30, column 1
Trigger.SiteSurvey_Trigger: line 4, column 1: []
```

This is my trigger code Before Update

```
private static void updateRiskScoreTotalOnSiteSurvey(List<Site_Survey__c> newSurveys) {

Map<Id, AggregateResult> surveyIdToSum = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
  [SELECT Site_Survey__c Id, SUM(Score__c) riskScoreTotal
  FROM Site_Survey_Response__c
  WHERE Site_Survey__c IN :newSurveys
  GROUP BY Site_Survey__c]);

for (Site_Survey__c survey : newSurveys){
  AggregateResult aggSum = surveyIdToSum.get(survey.Id);

  if(survey.Status__c == 'In_Review' ){
    Integer sum = Integer.valueOf(aggSum.get('riskScoreTotal'));
    if(sum != null){
      survey.Risk_Score_Total__c = sum;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the Test Case that's failing

```
@IsTest
  static void testRecordTypeUpdateReview() {
    Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> nameToRT =
      RecordType_Utility.getRecordTypesByDevName(
        Site_Survey__c.getSObjectType());

Schema.RecordTypeInfo inProgrgess =
  nameToRT.get(SiteSurvey_TriggerHandler.RecordType.In_Progress.name());
Schema.RecordTypeInfo review =
  nameToRT.get(SiteSurvey_TriggerHandler.RecordType.Review.name());
Site_Survey__c survey =
  [SELECT Id, RecordTypeId FROM Site_Survey__c LIMIT 1];
System.assertEquals(inProgrgess.getRecordTypeId(), survey.RecordTypeId);
List<Survey_Section__c> sections =
  [SELECT Id FROM Survey_Section__c WHERE Survey__c = :survey.Id];

for (Survey_Section__c section : sections) {
  section.Status__c = 'Complete';
}

update sections;
survey.Status__c = SiteSurvey_TriggerHandler.Status.In_Review.name();
Test.startTest();
update survey;
Test.stopTest();
survey = [SELECT Id, RecordTypeId FROM Site_Survey__c LIMIT 1];
System.assertEquals(review.getRecordTypeId(), survey.RecordTypeId);
```

}

Comment: is `aggSum` non-null inside the for loop?

Comment: [Safe navigation operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm) is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If zero rows would be returned, there's no entry in the map for the record, so you need to check for that first:

```
private static void updateRiskScoreTotalOnSiteSurvey(List<Site_Survey__c> newSurveys) {
    Map<Id, AggregateResult> surveyIdToSum = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
        SELECT Site_Survey__c Id, SUM(Score__c) riskScoreTotal
        FROM Site_Survey_Response__c
        WHERE Site_Survey__c IN :newSurveys
        GROUP BY Site_Survey__c
    ]);

    for (Site_Survey__c survey : newSurveys){
        if(survey.Status__c == 'In_Review' ){
            AggregateResult aggSum = surveyIdToSum.get(survey.Id);
            Integer sum = 0;
            if(aggSum != null) {
                sum = (Integer)aggSum.get('riskScoreTotal');
            }
            survey.Risk_Score_Total__c = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Map `surveyIdToSum`  is a Map from `Site_Survey_Response__c` Ids to `Site_Survey_Response__c`. However `survey.Id` is the Id of a `Site_Survey__c`. This is a different object, so it's Id won't be used as a key for `surveyIdToSum`. Hence `aggSum` is null, so calling `aggSum.get(...)` is giving you a NullPointer.